# Button1 Click error, I have no idea why this is happening

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Cursor.Position = New Point(150, 150)
    mouse_event(&H2)
    Cursor.Position = New Point(250, 250)
    mouse_event(&H4)
    Cursor.Position = New Point(250, 250)
    mouse_event(&H8)
    Cursor.Position = New Point(350, 350)
    mouse_event(&H10)
End Sub
```

The code above, I get an error with the `Button1.Click` and I cant figure out why:

> Handles clause requires a `WithEvents` variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

Comment: That means there must be a button in the enclosing class (usually the Form) named `Button1`.  Did you copy and paste that code to somewhere else in your project?

Comment: Easiest way would be to copy the code within the Sub, delete the entire sub, and button on the form; re-add the button object from the toolbox, double-click the new button, and paste the code back in.